# Confluence behind CloudFront displays java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Expected authority at index 2: //

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, confluence

I have Confluence running behind Amazon CloudFront. When users hit the base URL they get an error and a stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.net.URISyntaxException: Expected authority at index 2: //
```

I found an Atlassian Support page with a solution where an Nginx proxy was misconfigured. It indicated that removing the trailing slash from the proxy host would fix the issue, however I can't find any settings in the Origin or Cache Behavior to be able to set this in CloudFront.

Answer (score 0):

The default home page in CloudFront was set to `/`.  For confluence it needs to be `/wiki/dashboard.action`

Updating this fixed the issue.